# onCompletion handler with route scope fires in the middle of route

Tags: apache-camel

I have an issue with Camel 2.19.1. and `onCompletion` handlers with route scope. Runtime is Java 8, Karaf 4.0.9. The Camel context is built with Blueprint.

I have defined 3 routes with an onCompletion handler each:

```
<onCompletion mode="BeforeConsumer" parallelProcessing="false" onCompleteOnly="true" useOriginalMessage="false">
    <log message="<route_name> Success." loggingLevel="INFO" logName="policy-repository-adapter" />
</onCompletion>
```

The three routes call each other via the `direct` endpoint like so:

```
pra-soap-endpoint -> direct:xacml-policy-query -> direct:send-to-pas-endpoint
```

The top-level route `pra-soap-endpoint` looks like this (pseudo code, obviously):

```
route pra-soap-endpoint
  process
  log "route checkpoint 1"
  to direct:xacml-policy-query
  log "route checkpoint 2"
  process
end route
```

The log output from the top-level route and the onCompletion handlers looks like this:

```
route checkpoint 1
send-to-pas-endpoint Success.
xacml-policy-query Success.
pra-soap-endpoint Success.
route checkpoint 2
send-to-pas-endpoint Success.
xacml-policy-query Success.
pra-soap-endpoint Success.
send-to-pas-endpoint Success.
xacml-policy-query Success.
pra-soap-endpoint Success.
```

Note that the onCompletion handlers are fired multiple times. On top of this, the onCompletion handler of the top-level route is fired before the route actually finishes (log statement `pra-soap-endpoint Success.` before log statement `route checkpoint 2`).

What I expected was this:

```
route checkpoint 1
send-to-pas-endpoint Success.
xacml-policy-query Success.
route checkpoint 2
pra-soap-endpoint Success.
```

Is this a bug in Camel or a misconception on my end about how `onCompletion` handlers work?

Comment: I see 3 `xacml-policy-query Success.` lines. Could it be that your route is triggered in parallel and multiple threads are executing it? Try adding the thread name in the logs.

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna, it is just me sending POSTs from a test client. For every POST I am sending I am getting the log output with the same thread name and breadcrumb ID.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is **correct**. You specified `mode="BeforeConsumer"` on your `onCompletion` definition, and this changes the behaviour of Camel (since 2.14).

From [the docs](https://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html):

> From **Camel 2.14**: onCompletion has been modified to support running the completion task in either synchronous or asynchronous mode (using a thread pool) and also whether to run before or after the route consumer is done. The reason is to give more flexibility. For example to specify to run synchronous and before the route consumer is done, which allows to modify the exchange before the consumer writes back any response to the callee. You can use this to for example add customer headers, or send to a log to log the response message, etc.

Again, in its own section:

> onCompletion supports two modes
>   **AfterConsumer** - Default mode which runs after the consumer is done.
>   **BeforeConsumer** - Runs before the consumer is done, and before the consumer writes back response to the callee.
>   The AfterConsumer mode is the default mode which is the same behavior as in older Camel releases.
>   The new BeforeConsumer mode is used to run onCompletion before the consumer writes its response back to the callee (if in InOut mode). This allows the onCompletion to modify the Exchange, such as adding special headers, or to log the Exchange as a response logger etc.

---

As a solution, either use `AfterConsumer` mode or set pattern as `InOnly`.

Comment: Why should the onCompletion callback be called in the middle of the route? To me that does not seem useful. The route is not done and more processing steps follow. I would think that useful behavior would be to trigger the callback after the last processing step of a route but before sending the exchange back to the caller.

Comment: @Ralf what you describe is the normal behaviour. With `BeforeConsumer` mode you change how Camel calls onCompletion callbacks. The example provided in the docs says so you can add custom headers before sending to chid routes.

Comment: My understanding of the `onCompletion` hook is that it is all about "post processing" the exchange after the route (the consumer) is done. The before/after consumer modes only move the point in time of the post processing to before or after the exchange is returned to the caller of the route. Thus whether you can impact the response the caller receives or not. My understanding of what you are saying is that the `BeforeConsumer` mode allows massaging the Exchange before sending it to child routes. But that is what pretty much every route does and has nothing to do with "completing" the route.

Comment: I agree that a different name/command would have been more suitable. I think that BeforeConsumer mode acts similar to onPrepareRef of Splitter: https://camel.apache.org/splitter.html